# Prevent eclipse from putting static imports on top

Tags: eclipse

Is there anyway I can stop eclipse from moving static imports to the top? We have code that doesn't have static imports on top and every time i hit organize imports it causes a long diff in the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can define the preferred sort order in the "Organize Imports" preferences. This tab also allows you to specify where you want specific static imports.

If you want Eclipse to not change the order of imports at all, then you must never use "Organize Imports." Use "Remove Unused Imports" instead.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want eclipse to reorder my imports. I want eclipse to leave them as they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can add both normal and static imports with *, and then choose the order.

[image]